# Element UI Table Column that uses slot-scope Issue "Cannot read property 'column_name' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

Anyone here uses element ui framework? https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/

I'm using its table component and using slot-scope on its columns. It's working fine until I ran npm update which of course updates the packages. Now, console has a lot of errors. And later I discovered that this slot-scope of the table column causes the issue.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Here is a fiddle of the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/japhfortin/jkzma0v8/3/

```
  <el-table :data=list>
    <el-table-column label="First Name">
      <template slot-scope="scope">{{ scope.row.first_name }}</template>
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="last_name" label="Last Name">
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>

  data() {
    return {
      input: '',
      list: [
      {
        first_name: 'Foo',
        last_name: 'Bar'
      }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, and my solution is to just rollback my vue version until element updates to support the new slot syntax. See https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/issues/14303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed on Vue@2.6.3

Answer (score 4):

The error is thrown because the value `scope` is an empty object on the first render. It means that the object row is undefined an it throws. You have to check that the `row` value is defined before accessing it. You can also use their alternative form to bind the value to the column. It depends of your use case.

```
<el-table :data="list">
  <el-table-column prop="first_name" label="First Name"> </el-table-column>
  <el-table-column prop="last_name" label="Last Name"> </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

You can also use a `v-if` on the `scope.row` to ensure that the value is present at render time.

```
<el-table :data="list">
  <el-table-column label="First Name">
    <template slot-scope="scope" v-if="scope.row">
      {{ scope.row.first_name }}
    </template>
  </el-table-column>
  <el-table-column prop="last_name" label="Last Name"> </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

Comment: is it part of the vuejs update or element ui update? Because it was all working fine before. Their documentation also has this slot-scope example - https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#multiple-select

And I have to add something inside the cell that uses the data inside, that's why I needed this slot-scope to work.

Comment: You can use a `v-if` on `scope.row` to ensure that the value is present. I've updated my example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because of new slot syntax in Vue.
More information at https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0001-new-slot-syntax.md

Default slot with text

```
<!-- old -->
<foo>
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        {{ scope}}
    </template>
</foo>

<!-- new -->
<foo v-slot="scope">
    {{ scope}}
</foo>
```

Another example using the Table component of the UI element.

Note: Upgrade the Vue to the latest version, currently it is 2.6.3.

```
<el-table :data="list">
    <el-table-column label="First Name" v-slot="scope">
        {{ scope.row.first_name }}
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="last_name" label="Last Name">
    </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```